# .Net Core 2.1.2 version settings & Controller scaffolding (Sequence Contains No Elements)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have been troubling with .Net core 2.1.2 update. We have a .Net core project and we are developing that in two different machine ( win 10.0.17 ) , interesting thing is coming up here; he has the same project and even same sdk and runtime updates and evenmore he has **vs2017 15.7.5** update. He can run and build the Web Api without error but I have couple of problems shown in image name of buildError.

First [image: dotnet -versions]

Second [image: dotnet -info]

Third [image: nugets]

and finally **buildERROR** [image: builderror] 

`Error       The project was restored using Microsoft.NETCore.App version 2.1.2, but with current settings, version 2.1.0 would be used instead.  To resolve this issue, make sure the same settings are used for restore and for subsequent operations such as build or publish.  Typically this issue can occur if the RuntimeIdentifier property is set during build or publish but not during restore.`

Oh before forget, here is the error when I'm trying to add a new controller. [image: webApi error]

i will appreciate it, if we solve that.

> Note: I already clear the nuget cache file. And did not work.

Below, my csproj :  [image: api.csproj]

Comment: Does this issue exist in a new Asp.Net Core 2.1 project? Could you share us your `csproj` content? A reproduceable project would be helpful. Try suggestions from [After upgrading to ASP.NET Core 2.1, get error that project will use 2.1.0-rc1. How to fix? #3221](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3221)

Comment: @Edward , given your helpful information I just tried all of the solution, Sadlly problem still exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have other .net Core SDK's and Runtimes e.g ".Net Core Runtime 2.1.302" and ".Net Core Runtime 2.1.301" and even if you had download ".Net Core SDK 2.1.201 " &  ".Net Core SDK 2.1.202 "

You only need to be sure exact versions of SDK's and Runtime. I'll leave my version below in the image

[image]

Best Regards ;)

Comment: You saved my three nighmare day ! Best of luck to you :)